SQL code repeats result for first row only
I need to concatenate columns in an alphabetical order, so I used solution provided here: Marketing Cloud - SQL Contatenate columns in alphabetical order
select
stuff(x.c,1,1,'') as [constraint]
from OCP_CONTACT_EVENT_REASON_DETAIL_Constraints
cross apply (
  select top 3 '|' + rtrim(y.c) from (
    select constraint1 as c from OCP_CONTACT_EVENT_REASON_DETAIL_Constraints
    union all
    select constraint2 as c from OCP_CONTACT_EVENT_REASON_DETAIL_Constraints
    union all
    select constraint3 as c from OCP_CONTACT_EVENT_REASON_DETAIL_Constraints
  ) as y
  order by y.c
  FOR XML PATH('')
) x(c)

However, when I tried this code it keeps repeating the result only for the first row from the Data Extension.
Could you please have a look?



Could you also include the SQL query in text on the question for any answerer's benefit

Done, could you please take a look?

Please update your question to include some simple data from OCP_CONTACT_EVENT_REASON_DETAIL_Constraints.

Even better, update the dbfiddle from my previous answer with some sample data that's more realistic to your use case.
